# Command Bar in Windows Phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

I am using Command Bar in windows phone using below code

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar Foreground="White">
            <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
                <AppBarButton x:Uid="Share">
                    <AppBarButton.Icon>
                        <BitmapIcon UriSource="/Assets/Share.png"/>
                    </AppBarButton.Icon>
                </AppBarButton>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Favorite"></AppBarButton>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Comment"></AppBarButton>
            </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
```

I am getting a footer icon like below with out any background. Simply the icon image is showing.

[image]

But i need a footer icon like this with some rounded background for each icon with foreground white

[image]

Please guide me to achieve the expected

Comment: Dare I say "What have you tried?" "What Problems are you facing?" "What is it that you're confused about?"

Comment: I implemented command bar using the code i have posted. I have enclose the image(1st image) which i am getting based on the code i have used but i want to achieve the footer as 2nd image

Comment: So add some more buttons?

Comment: Please see difference of the icon in 1st it displays as plain one but in second image it is having a rounded background

Comment: Okay, now we're getting somewhere. Please post that in your question and anything else that you are trying to achieve. Do you see how your question is open ended?

Comment: Yes. I will include. thank you

Comment: Is this a UWP app, a Silverlight for Windows Phone app or something else?

Comment: S its a UWP app, a silverlight for Windows app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to follow below:

1) Open the page in Blend which you want to modify. Click on the actual Control and Right Click.

[image]

2) From the popup window choose Create new template and Define In as Application

[image]

3) It creates a copy of Default Template in App.xaml. Now Look For tag `ContentPresenter` before the end of style. It will be wrapped in StackPanel with Name ContentRoot. Wrap it with a Border.

```
<Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" CornerRadius="50" BorderThickness="2" Margin="10,0">
```

Finally It should be like below.

```
<Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" CornerRadius="50" BorderThickness="2" Margin="10,0">
    <StackPanel x:Name="ContentRoot" MinHeight="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}">
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="0,12,0,4"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextLabel" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" Margin="0,0,0,6" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Label}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Now go back to your page and set the style to this style key. Like Below.

```
<AppBarButton Icon="Favorite" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle1}" ></AppBarButton>
```

This is Beauty of Blend. Not just this control, you can modify any control that has Style Template.

Good Luck.