# How can I change label position of Xaml AppBarButton (Windows UWP)

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

In the Windows 10 UWP Xaml application AppBarButton control it is possible to define a custom icon. However there seems to be no way to position the label inside the button so if you want a bigger icon you can not as the label is overlapping the icon.
Is there a way to move the position the label inside the AppBarButton?

Here is the image displaying the behaviour:
[image]

As you can see from the designer and the editor I have a custom AppBarButton.Icon setup but the label is just over it.
I can modify the height and position of the Icon but not the label.

Some background:
The application is a migration of the Windows 8.1 Store application and that version had round circles around the icons. In the new Windows 10 UWP 'theme' the circles are gone and the customers would like to have them back.

Comment: try to make right click of mouse at `Label` and create `EditTemplate`->`Edit a Copy`. You should have a `ControlTemplate` where you can do what you want(change `Label` position, even delete `Label`).

Comment: @StepUp: Thanks, I will try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered this questions few days ago for another stack overflow member. See below.

[Command Bar in Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224842/command-bar-in-windows-phone/38230786#38230786)

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out.